# How can I annotate a file given a changeset?

Tags: visual-studio, tfs

I have a class where I modified a line and checked-in.

I want to track who previously changed this line.

I got the changeset of the check-in that I want to annotate: C854874. I got this changeset by comparing my latest change with the previous change. So my change is C85487**5** and the previous change is C85487**4**.

Is it possible to annotate a file given a changeset? How?

Answer (score 0):

Sounds like you want to pre-arranged the changeset ID. No, it's impossible. It's contrary to the principle of source control. Since you have no idea whether others in your team will check in something and generated a new changeset before you check in your changes.

If you just want to track who previously changed this line. You could use Annotate function in TFS. Just need to select the code line and right click **Source Control** and select **Annotate**.

[image]

Then you will get a related info including changeset ID, owner, date and comment...

[image]

More details please refer this link: [View file changes using annotate](https://www.visualstudio.com/en-us/docs/tfvc/view-file-changes-using-annotate)